# Prove that two vectors in Hilbert space are orthogonal

Tags: hilbert-spaces

Let $x$  and $y$ be two vectors in a Hilbert space $H$.Prove that $\left\|x+cy\right\|\geq\left\|x\right\|$ for all complex number $c$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal.

It's easy to show that if $x$ and $y$ are orthogonal,then the inequality is valid.For the converse conclusion, I think we can choose some special value of $c$ to obtain that $<x,y>=0$. But I don't know how to choose some proper $c$ to get result.

Comment: Suggestion - square both sides and expand the lhs....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on the suggestion in the comments:

Assume $A=\langle x, y \rangle \ne 0$. After replacing $y$ with $\alpha\, y$, with  non-zero $\alpha \in \mathbb C$,  you can assume that $A$ is (non-zero) real. At that point, square the inequality, and expand the lhs - you may take  $c$ to be real to find your desired contradiction.

Hope this helps.

Comment: When I expand lhs, I get that $2c<x,y>+c^{2}<y,y>\geq 0$.But I can't find the contradiction. Can you help me?Thank you in advance.

Comment: under the assumptions of the above hint, the lhs of what you've just written is a real quadratic in $c$, with two distinct real roots  (since $\langle x, y\rangle$ and therefore also $\langle y,y\rangle$,  are non-zero) - one of roots  is $c=0$: hence the quadratic must be negative on one side of $c =0$ (viewing $c$ as a real parameter) - you can see this by factoring - contradiction

Comment: other version:  for small $c$, the lower order term (here, linear) dominates, and it can be both positive and negative, and thus the whole expression can be both positive and negative. Okay?

Comment: clearer version of my first comment, perhaps:  - with $c$ real: for large $|c|$, the quadratic is indeed positive, but between its two (distinct) roots, the quadratic is negative (which is your desired contradiction). This we can by factoring the quadratic. Okay?

Comment: I got it. Thank you for your beautiful explanation!